# How to Proxy Rest API endpoint on Apache HTTPd. React Frontend and NodeJS Rest Endpoints

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js

Ive been trying to figure how to proxy my REST API endpoints in in Apache HTTPD.

- Apache HTTPD 2.4.6 (Centos)
- Front End - React Appliction (create-react-app)
- Node JS API Endpoints via port 9000. Im using a nodejs gateway called fast-gateway.
- Rest Endpoint served using self-signed certificates. For development environment only, will change once we get to production.

I've configured the SSL.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d as follows:

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/webserver/html/build"
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca.cer
        SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/certs/WEBSERVER.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/WEBSERVER.key

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        #PROXY
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyTimeout 1200

        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        #RewriteEngine on
        ProxyPass /business https://appserver:9000
        ProxyPassReverse /business https://appserver:9000/
 
Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes

</VirtualHost>

# intermediate config
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
SSLSessionTickets       off

SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

Once I perform a request on the frontend, I get an error 404 when calling the endpoints

```
Request URL: https://webserver/business/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 192.168.56.129:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

My sites-available config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName webserver
        ServerAlias webserver
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webserver/html/build

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Should I do a URL rewrite? supposedly the endpoint address should be  https://appserver/business/api/login, could this be the reason for 404? or have I configured anything incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

To proxy https://webserver/business/api to https://appserver:9000/business/api, you need

```
ProxyPass        /business/ https://appserver:9000/business/
ProxyPassReverse /business/ https://appserver:9000/business/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did what you suggested, I'm not really familiar with Apache HTTPD, its my first time trying out front-end dev. Anyway, with the changes in configuration, what am should I expect the URL for the post request to be? Should it now show `Request URL: https://appserver/business/api/login
Request Method: POST`. After the changes, I am now getting Error 500, with URL still reflecting as `https://webserver/business/api/login`. I made the config changes in SSL.conf. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /business/ [NC]
    RewriteRule /business/(.*) https://appserver:9000/business/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [P,L] [R=307]
```

i read that the Redirect flag must be 307 for the mode of the requests to be passed as they are. Please let me know if it works for you.